# Secure ldap problem

Tags: ldap, openldap, security

I have tried to config my openldap to have secure connection by using openssl on Debian5.  By the way, I got trouble during the below command.
ldap:/etc/ldap# slapd -h 'ldap:// ldaps://' -d1

```
>>> slap_listener(ldaps://)
connection_get(15): got connid=7
connection_read(15): checking for input on id=7
connection_get(15): got connid=7
connection_read(15): checking for input on id=7
connection_get(15): got connid=7
connection_read(15): checking for input on id=7
connection_get(15): got connid=7
connection_read(15): checking for input on id=7
connection_read(15): unable to get TLS client DN, error=49 id=7
connection_get(15): got connid=7
connection_read(15): checking for input on id=7
ber_get_next
ber_get_next on fd 15 failed errno=0 (Success)
connection_closing: readying conn=7 sd=15 for close
connection_close: conn=7 sd=15
```

Then I have search for "unable to get TLS client DN, error=49 id=7" but it seems no where has a good solution to this yet. 
Please help. 
Thanks

#

Well, I try to fix something to get it work but now I got this 
ldap:~# slapd -d 256 -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.11 (Nov 26 2009 09:17:06) $ root@SD6-Casa:/tmp/buildd/openldap-2.4.11/debian/build/servers/slapd could not stat config file "/etc/openldap/slapd.conf": No such file or directory (2) slapd stopped. connections_destroy: nothing to destroy. 
What should I do now?

**log** :
ldap:~# /etc/init.d/slapd start

Starting OpenLDAP: slapd - failed.

The operation failed but no output was produced. For hints on what went
wrong please refer to the system's logfiles (e.g. /var/log/syslog) or
try running the daemon in Debug mode like via "slapd -d 16383" (warning:
this will create copious output).

Below, you can find the command line options used by this script to
run slapd. Do not forget to specify those options if you
want to look to debugging output:
  slapd -h 'ldaps:///' -g openldap -u openldap -f /etc/ldap/slapd.conf

```
ldap:~# tail /var/log/messages

Feb  8 16:53:27 ldap kernel: [  123.582757] intel8x0_measure_ac97_clock: measured 57614 usecs
Feb  8 16:53:27 ldap kernel: [  123.582801] intel8x0: measured clock 172041 rejected
Feb  8 16:53:27 ldap kernel: [  123.582825] intel8x0: clocking to 48000
Feb  8 16:53:27 ldap kernel: [  131.469687] Adding 240932k swap on /dev/hda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:240932k
Feb  8 16:53:27 ldap kernel: [  133.432131] EXT3 FS on hda1, internal journal
Feb  8 16:53:27 ldap kernel: [  135.478218] loop: module loaded
Feb  8 16:53:27 ldap kernel: [  141.348104] eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex
Feb  8 16:53:27 ldap rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="3.18.6" x-pid="1705" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] restart
Feb  8 16:53:34 ldap kernel: [  159.217171] NET: Registered protocol family 10
Feb  8 16:53:34 ldap kernel: [  159.220083] lo: Disabled Privacy Extensions
```

Comment: It looks like something is connecting, but not communicating the Distinquished Name properly. It could be a misconfigured client or another process entirely trying to talk to that port.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your question needs editing. It is not clear.

It might be a good idea to start with a working setup without SSL and then adding bits and pieces one by one until something breaks so that you can find the problem. If the problem is with GnuTLS not supporting TLSCipherSuite, then take it away. Do you really need it? Why do you insist on OpenSSL? GnuTLS has worked fine for me, including LDAPS -connections on port 636, you don't need OpenSSL to do that.

Comment: SSL is only I know how to, I could not find document on howto do tls yet.

Comment: TLS and SSL are the same thing. Always on SSL/TLS differs from StartTLS however.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to this link 
http://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup
It said 
"Diagnosis:
If you try to install the OpenLDAP server (slapd) with Debian Lenny, it comes compiled against the GnuTLS library. It means you cannot use an OpenSSL style directive like TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2 in slapd.conf. "

I think it means that on Debian5 (Lenny) can not use openssl as security connection.
Maybe that why I never accomplish it ...Do you guys think it is so?

Comment: GnuTLS and OpenSSL are SSL/TLS-libraries. OpenLDAP can be compiled against either of them. GnuTLS just doesn't support all OpenSSL options. But SSL-connections work just fine using GnuTLS, I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would ignore the message "connection_read(15): unable to get TLS client DN, error=49 id=7" unless you have changed the default TLSVerifyclient, which by default is "never".

On the client side, tls_reqcert by default is "demand".

Try adding the ca cert on client side, or change tls_reqcert to never.